# Function browseVignettes() in R not returning anything

Tags: html, r, vignette

When I use browseVignettes() with no arguments, I should get a list of vignettes for all my installed package, however, no html file opens at all. The same goes when I pass a specific package as an argument for the function. Please help

Comment: It works as expected for me.  Have you tried, clearing the global environment, restarting R, etc?

Comment: Tried all that. Still not working..